# Editing display names and copying profile to all Stack Exchange Network accounts results in no entry for change in name in other sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, moderator-tools, display-names

As a mod, I can head over to a user's profile page & look up info on their account history - login/logout dates, suspension dates, change in display names and so on.

However, if a user changes their display name from another Stack Exchange account (example: Stack Overflow) and copies them to all other network sites, then the change in display name is not recorded in the other sites.

For instance, I changed my display name from Sathya to sathyabh.at from my Stack Overflow user page & opted to copy this to all accounts.

However, this is not reflected in my Super User account history.

[image]

Note that the change in name from Sathya to sathyabh.at is not recorded. I reverted the change from Super User, and that *is* recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next deploy will fix this.

The same "edit displayname" record will be created on all sites, with those set by a sync getting a slightly different comment indicating that.